# Elasticsearch infer _id on dynamic type when using IndexMany

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to get my head around a problem. I am building an application where we are indexing *assets* in Elastic. The nature of the *assets* is very dynamic, because they contain client metadata, which is different from client to client.

Because of this, the Index is built from a List of dynamics in C#. This actually works like a charm. The problem is, I cannot control the _id property in Elastic when using the C# interface. This means when I update the documents, instead of updating the correct one a new duplicate is made.

My code looks like this:

```
List<dynamic> assets = new List<dynamic>();
var settings1 = new ConnectionSettings(
    new Uri("http://localhost:9200")
    ).DefaultIndex("assets");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings1);

//assets is build here

var indexResponse = client.Indices.Create("assets");
var BulkResponse = client.IndexMany(assets);
```

This actually works and the index is built as I expect it to - almost. Even though I have a property called Id on the dynamic, it is not inferred correctly, which means the document is given an _Id decided by Elastic. Thus the next time I run this code using the same Id a new document is created rather than updated.

I have been searching high and low, but cannot seem to find a good solution. One thing I have tried is the following:

```
var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(bd => bd.IndexMany(assets, (descriptor, s) => descriptor.Id(s.Id)));
```

But this throws an error I cannot catch in the .net kernel. This actually works on lower versions on Elastic, but seems to have been broken with 7.2 and 7.0.1 of the C# interface.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: so i guess you are on ES7 and using Nest 7, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow the following to work

```
var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(bd => bd.IndexMany(assets, (descriptor, s) => descriptor.Id(s.Id)));
```

You just need to cast the `Id` type to the type that it is. For example, if it's a `string`

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var assets = new dynamic[] 
{
    new { Id = "1", Name = "foo" },
    new { Id = "2", Name = "bar" },
    new { Id = "3", Name = "baz" },     
};

var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(bd => bd.IndexMany(assets, (descriptor, s) => descriptor.Id((string)s.Id)));
```

This is a runtime limitation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of this limitation, but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `dynamic` type you could create dictionary-based custom type like:

```
    public class DynamicDocument : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public string Id => this["id"]?.ToString();
    }
```

and use it as follow:

```
class Program
{
    public class DynamicDocument : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public string Id => this["id"]?.ToString();
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex("documents");

        var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("documents");
        await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents");

        var response = await client.IndexAsync(
            new DynamicDocument
            {
                {"id", "1"}, 
                {"field1", "value"}, 
                {"field2", 1}
            }, descriptor => descriptor);

        //will update document with id 1 as it's already exists
        await client.IndexManyAsync(new[]
        {
            new DynamicDocument
            {
                {"id", "1"},
                {"field1", "value2"},
                {"field2", 2}
            }
        }); 

        await client.Indices.RefreshAsync();

        var found = await client.GetAsync<DynamicDocument>("1");

        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {found.Source.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"field1: {found.Source["field1"]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"field2: {found.Source["field2"]}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Id: 1
field1: value2
field2: 2
```

Tested with elasticsearch 7.2.0 and NEST 7.0.1.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is a brilliant idea. I have marked the other one as answer, as that technically is the correct answer, however, I just wanted you to know that the idea is good, and that I am most likely going to do something like this along the road. All though, i'll probably extend from dynamic instead. Thanks a lot!